# Fit a logistic regression code in R

Tags: regression, logistic

If I have 10 Variables (Q,W,E,R,T,Y,U,I,P,A) and I want Q  to be my response variable and other 9 to be my predictors variable. Do I write it in R like this

`EXAMPLE<-glm(Q~W+E+R+T+Y+U+I+P+A,family=binomial)`

Furthermore, what if Q is Binary (goes from 1 to 0) and  all the other 9 variables are categorically numbered. is it still the same or do i need to write it diff in R

Comment: Please explain: 'categorically numbered' and 'diff in R'

Answer (score 6):

If those are the only variables in the data frame (I presume you have then ten variables in a data frame? If not do it!), and that data frame is named `foo`, then the following is a simpler way to specify the model:

```
mod <- glm(Q ~ ., data = foo, family = binomial)
```

The `.` means *all variables not already specified in the model*.

`?glm` tells us what is acceptable for the response. This can be a numeric variable `0`, `1`, a factor with two or more levels (the first level is failure or `0`, the other levels are success or `1`), or a two column matrix with the first column being the successes and the second the failures.

If the predictor variables are numeric but should be factors, you should convert them first to factors. First look at the output from

```
str(foo)
```

and check whether the data types for the covariates are factor or not. Here is a worked example to follow using some dummy data in `foo`:

```
foo <- data.frame(A = sample(10, 5), B = sample(10, 5),
                  C = sample(10, 5))
```

`A` is the response, `B` and `C` are the covariates that should be factors. The conversion can be done as follows

```
foo <- data.frame(A = sample(10, 5), B = sample(10, 5), C = sample(10, 5))
want <- names(foo) != "A"
foo[want] <- lapply(foo[, want], as.factor)

> str(foo)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ A: int  4 1 5 3 10
     $ B: Factor w/ 5 levels "2","5","6","7",..: 1 3 5 2 4
 $ C: Factor w/ 5 levels "1","2","6","8",..: 3 2 1 5 4
```

Answer (score 0):

the correct way to fit such model in R is:
glm(Q~W+E+R+T+Y+U+I+P+A, family=binomial("logit"))

About the last question, I didn't understand if the independent variables are a) ordinal, b) non-ordinal, just with the numbers representing codes for nominal categories. In case a), you don't have to do anything. In case b), I recomend using factor(W) + factor(E) + ... factor(A). The regression output will show the results for each category of each variable, omitting just one which is the reference.

Comment: Better is to convert the variables to factors first before you fit the model via a formula. And you don't need to specify the `"logit"` as it is the default for the `link` argument.

Comment: what do you mean by Factor? and what is the R code for FACTOR. I am a beginner in R.  I am sorry for asking dumb question thank you.

Comment: @user24534 A factor is R's terminology for a categorical variable. You have to indicate to R which variables are factors if it doesn't work that out for itself (and it won't for numeric data).

Comment: Exactly, user24534: if you have categorical variables using numbers as codes, you have to tell R that they are categories. This is done with the factor() function. But as @Gavin-Simpson points in his reply, you could also do this for all variables before fitting the model.